# How to create a folder in svn repository on fedora

Tags: svn, fedora

Hi i did't used any version control system until now so basically i am newbie in using it.

Presently the os i am using is Fedora and svn for version controlling, suppose i had given below link to access files

```
http://example-theory.com/svn-repos/files/
```

When i clicked on it, i had given username and password and able to access all the files in it. for example the format is as below

```
svn-repos - Revision 4: /files

..
Examplefolder_1/
Newfolder_2/
```

But i want to create a separate folder with name `latest_files` and need to copy some `pdf files` and `.py` in to it.

How can i create a folder in svn repository
How to copy the pdf and other files in to it.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited Code:**

1. Installed subversion
2. Tried to creater a repository with this command `svnadmin create svn` 
   Created a folde svn
3. Tried to make a directory inside the folder `svn` with name `folder_example` with the following command

   svn mkdir folder_example

I recieved the following error

```
svn mkdir folder_example
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

My intension is to create a folder and import all the files from the link `http://example-theory.com/svn-repos/files/` and update and commit with changes in that.

Comment: Before 'clicking' on the link you should read some tutorial or introduction on version control and Subversion.

Comment: @Matteo: K i had the documentation and came to know that i need to install svn on my system and create a repository please find my edited code above

Comment: You don't need to **create** a repository. From what you say you need to check it out. (svn checkout). But you really need to google for a tutorial since it seem you are missing the basic concepts of version control.

Comment: k i will. but what if i want to create a separate folder in the repository and i recieved the above error, really i am unable to figure it out how to solve that anyway i will read documentation again, but please let me know why the above error appeared

Comment: Because you didn't check out the repository but tried to create a new one. You need to understand the basic concepts of version control without them it will be pointless to continue. Read the documentation on svn checkout (as mentioned earlier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Subversion client. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com

Comment: Please find my edited code above and let me the process i am doing is right or not